# How to prevent "304 Not Modified" in nginx?

Tags: header, nginx, http-status-code-304

I'm trying to disable all the caches in nginx for testing purpose.

I've set the following line

```
add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
```

I see that the page itself is not cached, but the images, css, and javascripts are. I suspect that this is because Firefox is getting "304 Not Modified" header.

Is there a way to prevent it?

P.S:

I think I found it myself. Firefox shows '200 OK' all the time now.

Is this correct way?

I've added

```
if_modified_since off;
add_header Last-Modified "";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds right to me.

If the agent (in this case Firefox) says 200 OK, it means the transfer happened.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use a location directive:

```
location ~ \.(html|css|js)(.*)$ {
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
}
```

Answer (score -16):

Another way is doing `ctrl + f5`